# How do I use objc_setAssociatedObject/objc_getAssociatedObject inside an object?

Tags: objective-c, categories

If I use objc_setAssociatedObject/objc_getAssociatedObject inside a category implementation to store a simulated instance variable in a setter method, how would I access the key in the getter method since any variables declared in the setter method would be outside the scope of the getter method?

**Edit:** To clarify, if I were to use the following pattern, where should I declare STRING_KEY so that I could use it in both the setter and the getter method.

```
@interface NSView (simulateVar)
-(void)setSimualtedString:(NSString *)myString;
-(NSString *)simulatedString;
@end

@implementation NSView (simulateVar)

-(void)setSimualtedString: (NSString *)myString
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &STRING_KEY, myString, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

-(NSString *)simulatedString
{
    return (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &STRING_KEY);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Declare a static variable so that you can use its **address** as the key.
The call to objc_setAssociatedObject takes a void* and only the address of your static variable is actually used, not the contents of a NSString... that is only wasting memory.

You just need to add:

```
static char STRING_KEY; // global 0 initialization is fine here, no 
                        // need to change it since the value of the
                        // variable is not used, just the address
```

Comment: the answer above initially referenced a link to apple docs that no longer exists.. [here](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ZKRevealingTableViewCell/blob/master/vendor/ZKRevealingTableViewCell.m) is an example that illustrates the answer above, although it's not in a category setter/getter context. If someone has a better example please share! For some reason the topic of associatedObjects isn't covered extensively in the web.

Comment: I think this is a super close example of what the OP is asking about: https://github.com/mystcolor/AFNetworking-ProxyQueue/blob/master/AFHTTPClient%2BProxyQueue.m#L149

Comment: Another nice key is a selector - I've been using this for a while, I read about this on some blog (Mike Ash? Mattt Thompson?).

Answer (score 38):

I know that this question is quit old but I think for completeness there is another way how to use associated objects worth mentioning. This solution utilizes `@selector` and therefore there is no need for any extra variable or constant.

```
@interface NSObject (CategoryWithProperty)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *property;

@end

@implementation NSObject (CategoryWithProperty)

- (NSObject *)property {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(property));
}

- (void)setProperty:(NSObject *)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(property), value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

(inspired by http://www.tuaw.com/2013/04/10/devjuice-better-objective-c-associated-objects/)

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Seems to be the most clearest for me.

Answer (score 23):

For associated storage `void *` keys, I like this way of doing it:

```
static void * const kMyAssociatedStorageKey = (void*)&kMyAssociatedStorageKey;
```

This avoids having another constant string in the executable, and by setting its value to the address of itself, you get good uniquing, and `const` behavior (so you'll nominally get a compiler complaint if you do something that would change the value of the key), without any extra unnecessary exported symbols.

Answer (score 17):

Declare a static (compilation unit-scope) variable at the top level of the source file.  It may help to make it meaningful, something like this:

```
static NSString *MYSimulatedString = @"MYSimulatedString";
```

Comment: I replaced my answer with one that answers your question, now I know what it is :-)

Comment: Thanks! This seems obvious enough. It seems my brain wants to encapsulate everything :).

Comment: Since this answer got un-accepted, to clarify: it's nice to have the value of the variable be meaningful because you can then print it from a debugger, even if you don't have debug symbols compiled into your program.

Answer (score 10):

Quite close. Here is a full example.

**.h-file**

```
@interface NSObject (ExampleCategoryWithProperty)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *laserUnicorns;

@end
```

**.m-file**

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void * LaserUnicornsPropertyKey = &LaserUnicornsPropertyKey;

@implementation NSObject (ExampleCategoryWithProperty)

- (NSArray *)laserUnicorns {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, LaserUnicornsPropertyKey);
}

- (void)setLaserUnicorns:(NSArray *)unicorns {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, LaserUnicornsPropertyKey, unicorns, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); 
}

@end
```

**Just like a normal property - accessible with dot-notation**

```
NSObject *myObject = [NSObject new];
myObject.laserUnicorns = @[@"dipwit", @"dipshit"];
NSLog(@"Laser unicorns: %@", myObject.laserUnicorns);
```

---

**Easier syntax**

Alternatively you could use `@selector(nameOfGetter)` instead of creating a static pointer. Why? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16020927/202451. Example:

```
- (NSArray *)laserUnicorns {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(laserUnicorns));
}

- (void)setLaserUnicorns:(NSArray *)unicorns {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(laserUnicorns), unicorns, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); 
}
```

Comment: Best answer! Only one that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer already got it right, but I'd like to add an explanation: the point of the "key" is to get a unique (per process/program) identifier that will not have any accidental collisions.

Imagine the key being declared as `NSUInteger`: lots of people would use standard values like `0`, `1` or `42`. Especially if you're using some library or framework, collisions are likely.

So instead, some clever Apple engineer had the idea to declare the key to be a pointer with the intent that you declare a variable and pass the *pointer to that variable* as a key. The linker will assign that variable an address that is unique within your application and so you are guaranteed to get a unique, collision free value.

In fact, you can pass any value you like, the pointer is not dereferenced (I've tested that). So passing `(void *)0` or `(void *)42` as the key does work, although it's not a good idea (so please don't do that). For `objc_set/getAssociatedObject`, all that matters is that the value passed as key is unique within your process/program.