# How to subclass a class which doesn't have any designated initializers?

Tags: swift

I am trying to subclass `MKPolyline`. However the problem is, `MKPolyline` does not have any designated initializers. Here is what I tried to do:

```
import MapKit

class MyPolyline: MKPolyline {
    let locations: [Location]

    init(locations: [Location]) {
        self.locations = locations

        var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        for location in locations {
            coordinates.append(location.coordinate)
        }
        super.init(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
    }
}
```

But I am getting `Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'MKPolyline'` error at the `super.init` call. To the best of my knowledge, `MKPolyline` does not have any designated initializers.

What should I do? How can I subclass a class which doesn't have any designated initializers?

Comment: does this need to be a convenience initializer and then call self.init with those properties ?

Comment: @JoshHamet Sorry, I did not understand what you meant. Could you clarify?

Comment: when you define a custom initializer that doesn't override any of the superclasses initializers, you need to prefix the initializer with convenience (conveniance init(locations: [Locations])). Instead of calling the designated intializer with a call to super, you make a call to self instead (self.init(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)

Comment: @JoshHamet If I make my initializer a convenience initializer, then trying to set `locations` using `self.locations = locations` gives `Cannot assign to property: 'locations' is a 'let' constant`.

Comment: can you assign the property after the designated initializer function call?

Comment: @JoshHamet I am not sure if it would make much sense. AFAIK, the purpose of an initializer is to set up properties and make the object ready to use.

Comment: I just meant to set the property after the designated initializer call within your convenience function rather than before which is the current implementation. From my understanding, you have to initialize the object (designated initializer) before you can reference self (your location constant instance property)

Comment: @JoshHamet You are confusing the issue. The base class (`MKPolyline`) has no public designated initializers. A subclass must declare at least one designated initializer. And a designated initializer must call `super` on a designated initializer in the baseclass. But the baseclass has no designated initializer. And a convenience initializer in a class must call a designated initializer in self. So you can't define a convenience initializer until there is a designated initializer. And in this case there is no way to create a designated initializer due to the base class. It's a problem.

Comment: @JoshHamet Also, in Swift, you set up the properties of `self` before calling `super`, but then only after you call `super` may you do anything with `self` other than set properties.

Comment: Related discussion in Objective-C: [Is it possible to inherit from MKPolyline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949069/is-it-possible-to-inherit-from-mkpolyline)

Comment: @rmaddy do you think this question should be closed as the linked duplicate in the above comment?  While the languages are different, the concept is the same.

Comment: @JAL IMHO, please not. Because I am usually having a hard time understanding Objective-C answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Designated Initializers

As you seem to know, designated initializers provide a way of creating an object from a set of parameters. Every Swift object must have at least one designated initializer, although in certain cases Swift may provide them by default.

In the case of a class, a default initializer will be provided iff all stored properties of the class provide default values in their declarations. Otherwise, a designated initializer must be provided by the class creator. Even if a designated init is provided explicitly, however, it is not required to have an access control level that would make it accessible to you.

So `MKPolyline` surely has at least one designated init, but it may not be visible to you. This makes subclassing effectively impossible, however there are alternatives.

Two alternatives immediately come to mind:

## Class Extensions and Convenience Initializers

One great feature of Swift is that classes may be extended even if the original class was defined in another module, even a third party one.

The issue you are running into is that `MKPolyline` defines convenience inits but no public designated ones. This is an issue because Swift has a rule that a designated init must call a designated init of its immediate superclass. Because of this rule, even a designated init will not work, even in an extension. Fortunately, Swift has convenience initializers.

Convenience inits are just initializers that work by eventually calling designated inits within the same class. They do not delegate up or down, but sideways, so to speak. Unlike a designated init, a convenience init may call either a designated init or another convenience init, as long as it is within the same class.

Using this knowledge, we could create an extension to `MKPolyline` that declares a convenience init which would call one of the other convenience inits. We can do this because inside of an extension it is just like you are in the original class itself, so this satisfies the same-class requirement of convenience inits.

Basically, you would just have an extension with a convenience init that would take an array of `Location`, convert them to coordinates, and pass them to the convenience init `MKPolyline` already defines.

If you still want to hold the array of locations as a stored property, we run into another problem because extensions may not declare stored properties. We can get around this by making `locations` a computed property that simply reads from the already-existing `getCoordinates` method.

Here's the code:

```
extension MKPolyline {

    var locations: [Location] {
        guard pointCount > 0 else { return [] }

        let defaultCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
        var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D](repeating: defaultCoordinate, count: pointCount)
        getCoordinates(&coordinates, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: pointCount))

        // Assuming Location has an init that takes in a coordinate:
        return coordinates.map({ Location(coordinate: $0) })
    }

    convenience init(locations: [Location]) {

        let coordinates = locations.map({ $0.coordinate })

        self.init(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
    }

}
```

Here's what's going on. At the bottom we have a convenience init very similar to what you already did except it calls a convenience init on `self` since we're not in a subclass. I also used `map` as a simpler way of pulling the coordinates out of `Location`.

Lastly, we have a computed `locations` property that uses the `getCoordinates` method behind the scenes. The implementation I have provided may look odd, but it is necessary because the `getCoordinates` function is Objective-C–based and uses `UnsafeMutablePointer` when imported to Swift. You therefore need to first declare a mutable array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` with exact length, and then pass it to `getCoordinates`, which will fill the passed array within the range specified by the `range` parameter. The `&` before the `coordinates` parameter tells Swift that it is an inout parameter and may be mutated by the function.

If, however, you need `locations` to be a stored property in order to accommodate a more complex `Location` object, you'll probably need to go with the second option described below, since extensions may not have stored properties.

## Wrapper Class

This solution doesn't feel as 'Swifty' as the previous, but it is the only one I know of that would let you have a stored property. Basically, you would just define a new class that would hold an underlying `MKPolyline` instance:

```
class MyPolyline {

    let underlyingPolyline: MKPolyline

    let locations: [Location]

    init(locations: [Location]) {
        self.locations = locations

        let coordinates = locations.map { $0.coordinate }
        self.underlyingPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
    }

}
```

The downside to this approach is that anytime you want to use `MyPolyline` as an `MKPolyline`, you will need to use `myPolyline.underlyingPolyline` to retrieve the instance. The only way around this that I know of is to use the method described by the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893517/is-it-possible-to-replicate-swifts-automatic-numeric-value-bridging-to-foundatio) in order to bridge your type to `MKPolyline`, but this uses a protocol that is undocumented and therefore may not be accepted by Apple.

Comment: I think this unfortunately doesn't work for me. Becuase `Location` is a struct which has a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` property, but it has other properties as well. So, I need a way to store the locations as a stored property. Given this, is there any way to achieve what I aim to?

Comment: Then you would probably want to go with the Wrapper class suggestion. I can update my answer to elaborate more on that if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for hours on SO (and on other sites) about this problem, but finally I could rewrite [a more generic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830861). Thanks for the original author :)