# Make only some UINavigationController's NavigationBar hidden?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I know how to make a navigationController's navigationBar hidden:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (custom)
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {}
@end
```

However, when displaying a UIImagePickerController it also applied to it.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; // Or whatever style.
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
```

Is there a way to only make some of the navigationController's navigationBar transparent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `-drawRect:` to behave differently for different instances of UINavigationBar, you could use something like `objc_setAssociatedObject` to record some indicator of whether it should be transparent. Then in `-drawRect:` you can use `objc_getAssociatedObject` on `self` to find out what to do.

Comment: That will hide the whole bar. I just want to make the background transparent (which is what that code does)...

Comment: You can set or clear this property in your view controllers' `-viewDidAppear` or `-viewDidDisappear` methods.

Comment: @jkbandes: can you give me a example of objc_setAssociatedObject? I have never worked with it before.

Comment: @Chaitanya Gupta I think I tried that before, but it didn't work. You have to have the drawRect for it to appear clear...

Comment: @phpnerd211: [this question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846218/how-do-i-use-objc-setassociatedobject-objc-getassociatedobject-inside-an-object) have some good information.

Comment: @jtbandes: I am so confused. How would I tell if it is a UIImagePickerController in the `drawRect:`? The link you provided confused me even more..Thanks!

Comment: You would probably want to to use `objc_setAssociatedObject` when you create it. Then in `drawRect:` you just check if the value is set.

Comment: @jtbandes: I've done some searching and I still can't figure it out! How in the world would you call the `objc_setAssociatedObject` when creating the UIImagePicker? How woud you read it? Thanks!