# How to add a variable to category in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, categories

It's requied to create a category with a new variable (of type NSArray).

OriginalClass+Extension.h:

```
@interface OriginalClass (Extension) {
    NSArray *_array;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *array;

@end
```

But I got the error: `Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol`.

Please help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other stated, you can't. Although has H2CO3 pointed out, you can use [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html).  On [Apple Documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html):

> Note that a category can’t declare additional instance variables for
>   the class; it includes only methods. However, all instance variables
>   within the scope of the class are also within the scope of the
>   category. That includes all instance variables declared by the class,
>   even ones declared @private.

If you want to go for associated object, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819092/how-can-i-add-properties-to-an-object-at-runtime) answer. Moreover, you can use [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/) post by Ole Begemann.

Comment: @Altaveron The same workaround that H2CO3 proposed, earlier ... (StackOverflow is strange :-) )

Comment: This answer has a link to exact code.

Comment: @Altaveron mine has the exact same link.

Comment: No! http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/

Answer (score 3):

You can't, a category can't declare additional instance variables ...

Reference : [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html) .

Comment: What should I use to add a new data variable to the class?

Comment: You will have to subclass though

Comment: I want to use the modified class with original class name.

Comment: You can't add an instance variable in a category, period .

Comment: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/

Comment: @Altaveron it is a workaround ...

Answer (score 2):

Simple: you can't add instance variables to a class using a category.

If you need to store additional data: use [associated objects.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html)

Comment: @Altaveron perhaps associated objects can help you. (See my edited answer.)

Comment: A category allows you to add methods to an existing class. Period. See  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html