# How can I add dynamically properties to an object at runtime in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Suppose (for the sake of argument) that i have a class in my iOS project which contains some treatments.

I want to know if it is possible to add dynamically properties to an Objective C object at runtime ?

I need to create dynamically, an object from an NSDictionnary instance wihch have a none fixed pattern of keys&vals. And to create the object with a generic way, i need that the Key from the NSDictionnary goes for the attribute name, and the Val goes for the attribute value.

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getFromJSON:(NSString *)json
{
JSONDecoder *decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] init];
NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *array = [decoder objectWithData:jsonData];
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
for (int i = 0; i < [data count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *modelData = [data objectAtIndex:i];
    // .... Object attributes creation goes here
```

At this Line,i need to create from this Dic (modelData) an object with attributes names that must correspond to the Keys of our Dic. The attributes of the created Object ( a dummy class) will be :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) key0;
@property (nonatomic, strong) key1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) key2;
```

.. and so On. is that possible ?

i'm creating a ModelManager and different Model subClasses that inherit from the ModelManager class with some specific actions.InThe ModelManager class,i have to do a generic method that creates an NSMuttableArray which contains the list of NSObjects.This objects corresponds to the data pulled from a Json request. 
Every Json request, returns data specific to one Model. I'm searching how to do this method with a generic manner to inherit it in the subclasses and just cast that dynamic object to the type of the subclass.The only generic way that i have found, is to create a dummy class with attributes created from the json data keys, afterwards cast this NSObject to the Model subclass class.

Comment: So what's wrong with just using an `NSMutableDictionary`?

Comment: Go to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819092/how-can-i-add-properties-to-an-object-at-runtime)
this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for yours comments, i have added some code for more clarification

Comment: Before we go into constructing a class at runtime, I think it might be better if you explained why you want to do this. The point of a class is that you have data and actions upon that data. Just putting random data into a class is going to be of limited use in which case you are better off just adding the dictionary to your general data class as a property.

Comment: i'm creating a ModelManager and different Model subClasses that inherit from the ModelManager class with some specific actions.InThe ModelManager class,i have to do a generic method that creates an NSMuttableArray which contains the list of NSObjects. (i have added the rest of the talk on my main Post ) thx.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it as a property.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary * dic;
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * dic;
```

And then later at runtime create it the way you want.

```
self.dic = @{randomKey : randomValue};
```

or

```
self.dic = [@{randomKey : randomValue} mutableCopy];
```