# dynamic initialize any objective C class with property

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, properties, nsobject

Can we initalize dynamically any Modal class. rather than creating any NSObject class with property values as likes string inside that class.

default we do code as like:
in .h file

```
@interface MyUser : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username,*bio,*website;
@end
```

in .m file

```
@implementation InstaUser
@synthesize bio;
@end
```

---

To use that we do:

```
MyUser *sendUser = [[MyUser alloc]init];
sendUser.username = @"JHON";
sendUser.bio = @"abcdcskdfhksfjhfkjsdf";
```

I Don't want to create so many this type of modal class rather then this just any dynamic method to initalize class property and use it by inline code.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean.

Comment: I have edited the question can any one have idea about this ? thanks in adv

Comment: Hi Shreeji u mean to say that you want to set all the properties of a class at one shot, i mean using one method ?

Comment: sounds like `NSMutableDictionary` with strong typed value accessors or CoreData model classes. give some code of what you want

Comment: @iamyogish . yes at one shot.  Not a single method but at-least from the single class at the time of using the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use run time feature of objective c class.
Create a single model class and add property to it dynamically at run time:
For more reference :

[How can I add properties to an object at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819092/how-can-i-add-properties-to-an-object-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks, using this I can add any number of property to my dynamic class: 
class_addProperty([SomeClass class], "name", attrs, 3);

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant a flexible model object with dynamically declared properties something like this:

```
MyModel *user = [[MyModel alloc] init];
user.name = @"name";

MyModel *something = [[MyModel alloc] init];
something.dynamicProperty = @"blahblah";
```

If so, you cannot. Use `NSMutableDictionary` instead, or consider to generate model classes from a simple config file by some scripts.