# ios - Swift add the properties programatically to entity

Tags: ios, swift, entity

I need to add the properties to entity programatically, based on my service response.

For Ex:  at the time of creation

```
class StockEntity : NSObject {
 var Apples : String,
 var Oranges : String
}
```

After some execution, may be it will add some more properties like, Grapes, Melons.

The newly adding properties are not aware at the initial.

I need to have this values in entity as based on this the calculations will happen.
Right now I have done this feature with Dictionary. And I am looking for the most optimal ways.

Comment: A dictionary sounds like a perfect fit for your use-case. What problems are you having with that approach?

Comment: Although what you are looking for could propably be accomplished via associated objects ( http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/ ), I strongly advise against this. It introduces a lot of complications and makes your code harder to maintain.

Comment: You can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819092/how-can-i-add-properties-to-an-object-at-runtime

Comment: Dictionary or a Collection Type seems perfect match for dynamic sized Homogeneous typed items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an struct rather than a class, just like this example:

```
struct ex {
    var x: String
}
extension ex{
    var y: String{
        get{return "a"}
        set(value){
            y = value
        }
    }
    init(x:String, y:String){
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

ex(x: "", y: "")
```