# hacky use of NSMutableDictionary to map on non-copyable objects

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'd like to create an NSMutableDictionary that's keyed on a particular object and maps to an NSNumber.  The object comes from a 3rd-party library and doesn't implement the copyWithZone method.  The compiler understandably complains about the unrecognized selector (copyWithZone) being sent to the object, using the code:

```
[dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index] forKey:someObject];
```

Since I didn't want to create my own copyWithZone method for a 3rd-party library object which I shouldn't need to know how to copy, I stayed away from creating a category that implements the method.

My hack was to store the memory address in an NSNumber by converting it to a long long:

```
[dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:(long long)someObject]];
```

To retrieve the value:

```
NSNumber *indexNumber = [dictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:(long long)someObject]];
```

This seems very hackish to me.  What would be a cleaner way to handle the object-to-int mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use associated objects...

See [How do I use objc_setAssociatedObject/objc_getAssociatedObject inside an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846218/how-do-i-use-objc-setassociatedobject-objc-getassociatedobject-inside-an-object)

That q/a has a good example.

(Associated objects allow you to associate an arbitrary set of objects with another object, using a key to look up any individual object.)