# Is it possible to send objects with UITapGestureRecognizer initWithTarget:action:

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I currently have this in my code

`tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(updateLeftLabel:)];`

which calls

```
- (void)updateLeftLabel:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
```

My code would be cleaner if the method was

```
- (void)updateLeftLabel:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer fromData:(EquationData*)data
```

However, I need a way to send the 'data' parameter when I init `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [associated objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) to attach `data` to the gesture recognizer.

Comment: I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846218/how-do-i-use-objc-setassociatedobject-objc-getassociatedobject-inside-an-object

Comment: but I'm having trouble understanding the implementation. Do you mind further explaining how I can add associated objects to my code?

Comment: The cleaner API you proposed suggests that `data` is ready by the time the gesture recognizer fires. Just associate `data` with `tap`, and you'll be able to retrieve `data` in `updateLeftLabel:`.

Answer (score 4):

Why Complicate ???
Subclass UITapGestureOrganiser and use any number of custom objects in the new class.