# declare two property and call objc_setAssociatedObject with same key

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

in category UIButton .h file:

```
@interface UIButton (zz)
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *param1;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *param2;
@end
```

in category UIButton .m file:    (note： all keys is 0)

```
@implementation UIButton (zz)
@dynamic param1;
@dynamic param2;

-(void)setParam1:(NSString *)param1{
     objc_setAssociatedObject(self, 0, param1, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
-(NSString*)param1{
    return (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, 0);
}

-(void)setParam2:(NSString *)param2{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, 0, param2, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
-(NSString*)param2{
    return (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, 0);
}

@end
```

below is test code:

```
....
....
UIButton *b1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIButton *b2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

b1.param1 = @"b1 1111";
b1.param2 = @"b1 2222";

b2.param1 = @"b2 1111";
b2.param2 = @"b2 2222";

NSLog(@"b1 param1=%@ param2=%@",b1.param1,b1.param2);
NSLog(@"b2 param1=%@ param2=%@",b2.param1,b2.param2);
```

output result:

```
2013-04-08 11:30:52.258 zazis[928:c07] b1 param1=b1 2222 param2=b1 2222
2013-04-08 11:30:52.259 zazis[928:c07] b2 param1=b2 2222 param2=b2 2222
```

**I would like to know why it is correct for same key???
  Thank you.**

Comment: i am not sure i understand your question. You are accessing the same object with both your properties, and so your output prints the last set object(s) "b1 2222" and "b2 2222" twice.

Comment: i'm sorry for my description unclearly, about objc_setAssociatedObject function is:
void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, const void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)

the second param  key is a void pointer. The key for each association must be unique. A typical pattern is to use a staticvariable(from apple).

Comment: but it is not unique in my code and works correctly.

Comment: object+key is unique, not the key alone. So sharing the same key for different objects is correct, but not sharing the same key for different properties of the same objects.

Comment: @xuanwenchao: It does *not* work correctly: You set `b2.param1 = @"b2 1111"` and the output is "b2 param1=b2 2222".

Comment: your are right ,I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846218/how-do-i-use-objc-setassociatedobject-objc-getassociatedobject-inside-an-object)

You used `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject` with the same key for both parameters, so they set/get the same object

Comment: thanks for for your answer, it is two property in my code(param1 and param2) and them setter method is same key, but output result is defferent.
[928:c07] b1 param1=b1 2222 param2=b1 2222
[928:c07] b2 param1=b2 2222 param2=b2 2222