# show contact images along with contact name in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I want to show phone contacts along with the pic in table view in alphabetic order.

I have managed to show contact name in correct order but unable to show images in correct order.

I have been trying these for few days but couldn't succeed .

I know how to sort array but don't know how to sort the image data.

please help me guys.

here is my demo code:

```
  NSArray *sortedFirstNames;

 - (void)getPersonDetails
 {
CFErrorRef error = NULL;

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

if (addressBook != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Succesful.");

    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    NSMutableArray *firstNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *firstimages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
    {
        Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];




        NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        NSString *fullName;
        if (lastName == nil)
        {
            fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", firstName];
            [firstNames addObject: fullName];
        }
        else if(firstName ==nil)
        {

                fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", lastName];
                [firstNames addObject: fullName];

        }
        else
        {
            fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
            [firstNames addObject: fullName];

        }

        person.firstName = firstName;
        person.lastName = lastName;
        person.fullName = fullName;


        //email


       imgdata=(__bridge NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contactPerson, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

        NSLog(@"newstris%@",imageStr);
        if(imgdata==nil)
        {

        }
        else
        {
        [firstimages addObject:imgdata];
        }





        [self.tableData addObject:person];
    }
    sortedFirstNames = [firstNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


}

CFRelease(addressBook);

}
```

code for showing images in cell:

```
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{


        UIImage *image1;

        //        cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
        if (person.imgdata==nil) {
            image1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_profile_pic.jpg"];
        }
        else
        {
          image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:person.imgdata];  
        }
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(6.5, 6.5, 45., 45.);

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell addSubview:imageView];

        });
    });
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Answer is pretty simple.

Add a field in your `Person` class which stores a `NSData`.
Like:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *imageData;
```

And use:

```
person.imageData = imgdata;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,I already did that but images are not shown with associated name.I want image along with there name in alphabetic order.(A-Z)

Comment: Are you sure that the image data is not null in the cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @VarunVishnoi: Did you used property ?

Comment: Yes,image is coming but in wrong order ...with this code I am sorting Contact name:sortedFirstNames = [firstNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

Comment: @VarunVishnoi: how are you showing the image in cells ? Can you show that code ?

Comment: @VarunVishnoi: why don't you use `cell.imageView.image` ? Also why you are using `dispatch_sync`

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue. I have fixed this issue by associate object like this.

while loading source array:

```
 objc_setAssociatedObject(hDetails, @"imageUrl", record, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

in cell for row at indexpath :

```
Record *record = objc_getAssociatedObject(hDetails,@"imageUrl");
```

for more reference see this :

[How do I use objc_setAssociatedObject/objc_getAssociatedObject inside an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846218/how-do-i-use-objc-setassociatedobject-objc-getassociatedobject-inside-an-object)