# ObjC/C syntax: static void *const Something = (void *)&Something;

Tags: objective-c, c

I have difficulty to understand this line of code:

```
static void *const Something = (void *)&Something;
```

How can "Something" appear on both sides of the equal sign? Thx!

Edit: What does it mean? Why do we need this kind of code? Is there other alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that `Something` is a pointer to itself in a static address space. It's usually used simply to create a unique value that can be used for keying, with functions such as `objc_getAssociatedObject`.

The container `Something` is going to end up in a fairly arbitrary location in memory, such as 0x12345. What that line of code is saying is the value of `Something` should be set to the address of `Something` (the `&` operator gives the address of the pointer). So you're putting 0x12345 into the memory location 0x12345. Because no other variable can occupy that memory address, `Something` is guaranteed to be unique with respect to any other variable created in this way.

Regarding the use of a variable on both sides of an assignment:

`x = x + 1;` doesn't seem strange at all, does it?

In the case of your question though, the declaration of `Something` is a statement that is valid before the "line" ends: `static void *const Something`.

`int x = x + 5;` is also valid, but x is uninitialized and so will likely contain a garbage value. `&Something` is asking for the address which is a real, non-garbage value as soon as `Something` was declared on the left hand side.

Comment: Thx Fabian! By searching "objc_getAssociatedObject" I found a similar mentioning of this topic in one of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846218/how-do-i-use-objc-setassociatedobject-objc-getassociatedobject-inside-an-object

Comment: Now I understand its purpose and usage. But the syntax still looks weird to me. I'm afraid I might have overlooked some basic language knowledge. So is there other similar concept like this one in ObjC/C? I mean using something on both sides of a single line of code. Or give me a guide/direction so I can continue reading. thx again :-)

Comment: Updated answer with some explanation of the syntax.

Comment: So there are 3 mind steps: declare Something; get its address; do assignment (to itself). In x = x + 1, I thought the compiler handled the right side x first, trying to find its declaration somewhere else.

Comment: The compiler will actually resolve both sides of the assignment operator before executing the assignment. C code such as `array[3] = 12;` should make that clear. Where `array` is a pointer, `array[3]` is essentially `array + 3 * (the size of whatever the array type is)`. The RHS value is put into the 3rd position of the array. So the line `array[3]` must have been evaluated at some point first.