# I want to create a category ,but appear this error,why?

Tags: ios, object

this error ，how to solve this error？

[image]

---

[image: two]

Comment: plz write down the sourcecode in sourecodeblock and dont upload as image

Comment: Have you read about categories and what they can and can't do?

Comment: See the below link it may helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846218/how-do-i-use-objc-setassociatedobject-objc-getassociatedobject-inside-an-object

Comment: You haven't implemented the method in the category.

Comment: The error messages seem quite clear - you haven't implemented the function that you declared in the category and you have called a function that hasn't been declared