# No matching function to call objc_getassociatedobject in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, objective-c++

I'm trying to develop an IOS application works with objC++. I am using [this GUI framework](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController) for designing my GUI. But, the problem is that XCode does not seem to recognise its own library objc/runtime.h or objc_getassociatedobject methods. It is an Objective-C method and it is rather surprising that i get this error. XCode gives error `No matching function to call objc_getassociatedobject` even though i `#import <objc/runtime.h>`.

[image: This is the error.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use objc\_setAssociatedObject/objc\_getAssociatedObject inside an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846218/how-do-i-use-objc-setassociatedobject-objc-getassociatedobject-inside-an-object)

Comment: You use incorrect call to function.

Comment: @JohnTracid What is the correct usage?

Comment: Check provided link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objc_getAssociatedObject()`'s second parameter has type `const void *`, whereas you are trying to pass a `NSString *`. C++ is pretty strict about implicit type conversions and it is not happy about such a conversion.