# How to get the name of the image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How to show the name of the image.

```
DetailCoverPage *detailCoverPage = [[DetailCoverPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailCoverPage" bundle:nil];
detailCoverPage.coverPage = image;


[self presentModalViewController:detailCoverPage animated:YES];
[detailCoverPage release];
```

here i need to get the name of the image
imageName is string.
detailCoverPage.imageName=???

how to get the name of the image?

Comment: I don't see an image in your code.

Comment: Can u please give more code and describe it. We cant conclude anything from your code and ur description of the code..

Comment: This is a duplicate question, please the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740274/uiimageview-how-to-get-the-file-name-of-the-image-assigned

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it using UIImage. One way to solve this problem if you really need it would be subclassing UIImage and adding a name attribute:

UINamedImage.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface UINamedImage : UIImage {

}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString * name;

-(UINamedImage *) initWithName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

UINamedImage.m

```
@implementation UINamedImage

@synthesize name = _name;

-(UINamedImage *) initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    self = [super initWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    _name = [name retain];
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [_name release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

there is the way, this code will help you out

```
    NSString *imgName = [self.imgView1st image].accessibilityIdentifier;

    NSLog(@"%@",imgName);

    [self.imgView2nd setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you can't. Once the image is initialized, it doesn't take it's name along on the ride. You'd have to store it in a separate member instead.
HTH
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

There is no name. All you have is a UIImage object. That's it.