# Assign string value as a image name

Tags: ios

I have a string variable(imageStr) in which I have name of an image I am fetching from `sqlite` database.  How can I assign that string variable as an image name to a `imageview`?

Code:

```
UIImageView *imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 11, 50, 25)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageStr];
imageHolder.image=image;
NSLog(@"image in mediView:%@",imageHolder.image);
```

In the log I am getting `NULL` value.   If I print just "**imageStr**" then it is giving me string value.

Comment: Are you have image (*.png or *.jpg) with same name as saved in imageStr-variable? If imageStr have a difference in name, your image will be a nil.

Comment: are you stored url in data base for that image?

Comment: what you are getting while printing imageStr?

Comment: it works if you have same image name in imageStr with image extemsion like [UIImage imageNamed:@"openTree.png"]

Comment: u are trying to print image ... !!! u cant get image name from UIImageView assigned image

Comment: better u see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740274/uiimageview-how-to-get-the-file-name-of-the-image-assigned

Comment: does that string hold the extension too . or else you have to add it

Comment: Please, in order to get useful answers, edit your question and show us what are you getting when you print "imageStr"

Answer (score -1):

`NSLog(@"image in mediView:%@",imageHolder.image);`

The above line of code is trying to print a UIImage, which makes no sense because neither `UIImageView` or `UIImage` have knowledge of what the name of the image is. What you need to do is subclass `UIImageView` and add a property that saves this information.

Update: [Shan's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740274/uiimageview-how-to-get-the-file-name-of-the-image-assigned) above is pretty helpful.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer