# how to get image name when click on uiimageview?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIScrollview. 
In the UIScrollview there are 4 UIImageViews with images.
When I click on any UIImageview I want to know the name of that image.

Comment: Are you loading it from an array?

Comment: yes but I don't want to use array. because it is very basic solution.

Comment: I want to something like When click on image it will give me name of image also. @AdeelUrRehman

Comment: You have to create your own ImageView and add a property that store the name of the image and also set the image to the image view.

Comment: Use tags to identify images. I don't think so there is a way to get image names from `UIImage` object.

Comment: What do you mean by `image name`?

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman I think it's bad practice to subclass uiimageview. can we use gesturerecognizer for that?

Comment: why you r not using custom UIButton instead of UIImageView ?

Comment: @stack you want to get the name of the image which you cannot get using the gesture recognizer. In your question you mentioned **I want to know name of that image**

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740274/uiimageview-how-to-get-the-file-name-of-the-image-assigned

Comment: thanks for quick reply all. I think subclassing uiimageview is good solution for that.

Comment: why do you need to know the _image's name_?

Comment: @holex because I have thumbnail image in my UIImageView and I want to download original image from server after click on thumbnail image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIImageView` just keeps the pointer to the place the `UIImage` is stored inside the memory, so it's not possible with `UIImageView`. You would need to create a subclass of `UIImageView` with a `NSString` variable which stores the value to access it later. Something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyImageView : UIImageView

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageName;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The image names are not stored in `UIImage` objects so you have to keep them somewhere else for lookup. To detect touches in image views you either have to subclass them and add code for touch detection, add tap recognizers or replace them with buttons.

Comment: I âm using tap Recognizers. how can get name of image using recognisers please?

Comment: For example, give each image view a tag that corresponds to the index of the image name in the array and use it to retrieve the name.