# Sorting UIImage Type Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift, uiimage

How do I sort images in order in an array type UIImage?

I'm query images from Parse, putting them in an AnyObject type array and converting it into  UIImage type array.

```
var imagesArray:[AnyObject] = []

var uiImageArray:[UIImage] = []
```

To display the images I'm doing this:

```
func updateImageOnUI() { //Changes the UI

    if imageCounter < self.imagesArray.count {
        var imageElement: AnyObject = self.imagesArray[imageCounter]


        var imageUpdate: AnyObject = self.imagesArray[imageCounter]
        println(imageUpdate["ImageFiles"])

        let userImageFile = imageUpdate["ImageFiles"] as PFFile

        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if !(error != nil) {
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                self.image.image = image
            }
        }



    } else {

        imageQuery()
    }


}
```

Problem is, I can't sort the images so that they appear in order. They are named "image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc"

How do I sort the images so that they repeat in order?

I've tried the sort function, but it's giving me errors

```
let sortedArray = sorted(imageList, {
    (str1:UIImage, str2: UIImage) -> Bool in
  return str1. /*not sure what to put*/ > str2./*not sure what to put*/    
})
```

The errors I'm redesign are saying that AnyObject or UIImage aren't compatible types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImageView - How to get the file name of the image assigned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740274/uiimageview-how-to-get-the-file-name-of-the-image-assigned)

Comment: var imageArray : [UIImage] = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image500.jpg", "image33.jpg", "image32.jpg"] And i'm trying to sort that in order basically...

Comment: What does 'parse' return to you when you query for 'images'?  An image name?

Comment: @GoZoner I get the assembly code: 0x71829292 for example, for each image.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get the `fileName` of an `UIImage` after it is set.

You could always store the array of `UIImage`s as `[(fileName: String, image: UIImage)]`. When you insert them, you add the filename (or other name you want to sort by). Then you can sort the array of tuples by `fileName`.